# Python: How can I troubleshoot this Function?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on an application and currently focusing on the database area.

I have successfully setup functions that create databases and write to them, however right now I am trying to retrieve specific rows from the database however NO MATTER WHAT I TRY I always get a syntax error DESPITE my SQL query running successfully in in [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org).

This is my trouble code:

```
def findapple():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('working.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM "working" WHERE "symbol" = 'aapl';')
        print row
```

If I understand the code I've written, it should connect to "working.db" create a cursor for the database then for each row that match my query it should be printed to the console.

Can anyone please help shed some light on this?

Thank you!

**Current Code Per comments below:**

```
def findapple():
conn = sqlite3.connect('working.db')
c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = 'aapl'')
    print row
```

and the error output:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stock import *
  File "/Users/ME/Documents/Code/Stocks/stock/database.py", line 61
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = 'aapl'')
```

Comment: you don't need the semicolon delimiter. Also skip the quotes around table/column names

Comment: @Sathya Still Fails with the following: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stock import *
  File "/Users/DJ/Documents/Code/Stocks/stock/database.py", line 61
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = 'apple' ')There is a carot under the L I swear to you I've been trying this all night and reading on sqlite syntax and so on, I just can't get this to work and I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot

Comment: You can't nest a single-quoted string `'aapl'` inside *another* single-quoted string `SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = 'aapl''`

Comment: So @IanMcLaird `'SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol ="apple" '`? What do you suggest?

Comment: Try flipping that the other way around.  I'm not sure about sqlite, but many SQL dialects require single-quotes for SQL strings.  Python doesn't really care which ones you use, but the sql interpreter might.  `"SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = 'aapl'"` may work.

Comment: no joy, I've verified my indentions (4 spaces) an they seem on point. I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: You're missing a `:` at the end of your `for` header.

Comment: THAT.....that was it. I am still such a noob with the programmings and the attention to detail. if you put that in an answer I'll mark yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your string syntax is wrong:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM working WHERE symbol = "aapl"')
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from stock import *
  File "/Users/ME/Documents/Code/Stocks/stock/database.py", line 61
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM "working" WHERE "symbol" = "aapl";')`

My Terminal is pointing at the closing parentheses. I am using python 2.7.10 on a mac updated all the way. is there any other information that i can give you to help troubleshoot this?